# How to create an android Project from existing source in eclipse with ADT 20.0.X and SDK r20

Tags: android, eclipse

Halo, there, Please any one to help me how to create a new a android Project in Eclipse from existing source, my eclipse is configured with ADT 20.0.2 and SDK r20,

Answer (score 6):

File->New->Project...->Android tab-> "Android Project from Existing Code"

Comment: Thanks, i have imported my project, but the only problem i have now is about the maps, as my project was using maps very well but after doing this on my New PC, now i ave alot of errors about com.google.android.maps.*, in my eclipse, but on my old PC, it works well, Please help me and highlight on this

Comment: Right-click your project and go to Properties. Then go to the Android section and change your Project Build Target to a version of the Google APIs that correlated with the API Level you wish to target.